# Smooth scrolling of document in either directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used the following function to scroll my document to specific point when user tries to scroll on the page. For this I used following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 700}, 500);
        return false;
    }
});
```

I want to know if there are event listeners for the mousewheel actions or not. When using this I can not actually scroll back up to the top of the document, because the scroll of mouse re-invokes the function and it pulls down the document again.

Also, if there is an alternative way, please let me know.
Can I do this using CSS only for cases where JS may be disabled by the user/client?

Comment: In CSS - no, it's impossible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: on mouse-wheel scrolling down, my document scrolls down to top = 700px (suppose). On the other hand, on mouse-wheel scrolling up, it should go to top = 0.
@iambriansreed

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

After your short explanation I (hopefully) understand what do you want. 
I made a function with position states:
header, content, unresolved

and I reused your scrolling function with state condition.

```
(function() {

var pagePosition = "header";

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0 && pagePosition == "header") {
        pagePosition = "unresolved";
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 700}, 500, function() {
            pagePosition = "content";
        });
        return false;
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 700 && pagePosition == "content") {
        pagePosition = "unresolved";
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500, function() {
            pagePosition = "header";
        });
        return false;
    }

});

})();
```